# Where is proguard-rules.txt in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

In my demo project, `proguard-rules.txt` is not available in Android studio.

I must be missing some code :

[image]

Where can I find **proguard-rules.txt** file?

I want to add proguard rules

Any help is appriciated

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like your project is missing proguard files. You can add it yourself: put the `proguard-rules.txt` file into the `app` directory. It's already added to your `build.gradle` file so no further actions required.

Comment: Android Studio older version do not include `proguard-rules.pro` automatically, so manually adding it works...Thank you !!

Answer (score 9):

`proguard-rules.txt` (or `proguard-android.txt`) are in your SDK folder, but if you want to add something to your ProGuard rules you should do this in `proguard-rules.pro`.

This file should be automatically added to your project by Android Studio when you create new (if isn't present - create manually). Check [DOC](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) (Gradle section ofc)

Comment: As you mentioned, I changed the line to `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` but still **proguard-rules.pro** is not added in Android studio project

Answer (score 6):

it is located under your `sdk` folder, usually in `yoursdk/tools/proguard/`. If you are using linux or mac, once you `cd` into the sdk folder you can run

```
find . -iname proguard-rules.txt
```

to look for it

Comment: I found the path.. I changed code to `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` but still Android studio project do not have **proguard-rules.pro** file for my project.. Where should I write proguard rules related to my project?

Comment: we keep it on the root of our project.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually create the file in the `\StudioProjects\your_project\app` folder and you can add the custom rules.